# ASCII 2D game-map

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Problem

Given input `a` where a is a grid of characters in any input format as long as it has only one element for each 'block' of the output.

And input `b` where b is a grid of numbers the same size as input `a`.

There are two types of road, a 1 represents a stone road marked by `@` and a 2 represents a dirt road marked by `#`

- A `@` road is centered in the block and is size 6x6, if a road is adjacent, that side is extended to grid cell border
- A `#` road is centered in the block is size 4x4, if a road is adjacent, that side is extended to grid cell border

Output a grid offset by line number of 8x8 of the ASCII character in input `a` and overlay a 'road' from input `b` e.g.

Input `a=[[a,b,a],[b,a,b],[a,b,a]] b=[[1,1,1],[2,0,1],[2,0,0]]`

Output:

Step 1: the grid (8x8 representation of input `a`)

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

Step 2: Overlay with roads represented by `b`:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
a@@@@@@abbbbbbbba@@@@@@a
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
bb####bbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

Step 3: Offset each line with linenumber:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
 a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
  a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
   a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
    a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
     a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
      a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
       a@@@@@@abbbbbbbba@@@@@@a
        bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
         bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
          bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
           bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
            bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
             bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
              bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
               bb####bbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
                aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                 aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                  aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                   aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                    aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                     aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                      aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                       aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

#### Rules:

- Leading whitespace or newlines allowed.
- Trailing whitespace and newlines allowed.
- This is code-golf so shortest code wins

[Here](https://pastebin.com/PWtcGx1x) is an extra test case with all edge cases in I can think of.

Comment: why only 1 newline allowed? can there be leading newlines (with whitespace)?

Comment: In the extra test case, array `a` is smaller than array `b`.

Comment: @dzaima Why should more be allowed?

Comment: @LiefdeWen they don't do any bad and give more golfing opportunities

Comment: @Zgarb fixed it, sorry all the commas blurred together.

Comment: @dzaima Okay, will ammend.

Comment: Now the `'1'` and some other characters seem to be in the wrong place.

Comment: @Zgarb fixed again.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is not well defined. First off, in your test case second row of input a is `['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.']`, but output is like that row was `[',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',']`.

Also, what prevents you to have this as output from your test case: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dfcf3b754464f3ca4394d34e9f3bf123

Notice that the second 1 from the first row of input b is adjacent to two 2's. Why did you chose to connect it only to first 2 (in the same row)?

Comment: Can we assume the elements in array `a` will never contain `@` or `#`?

Comment: @DarrenH yes that's fine.

Comment: In your second test case, rows 9 and 10, columns 35-38, your answer returns the value of a, but mine returns the value of b because there is a road to the north (of a different type, but still a road). Have I misunderstood the requirement or is this a mistake in your test case?

Comment: @guest44851 I see no problem with the question itself, however my test case was wrong but it shouldn't be like your example, it should be how DarrenH described it, it's fixed now

Comment: @DarrenH you are correct, fixed my second test case.

Comment: May we take multi-line or single-line strings as input?

Comment: @Titus any input format is acceptable as long as there are two distinct inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 250 <s>207</s> bytes

*Edit* Bug fix :(

A function taking inputs in currying syntax (a)(b).

```js
a=>b=>a.map((r,i)=>k.map(y=>(h+=' ')+r.map((c,j)=>k.map(x=>(t=x<v,s=x>7-v,!v|t&(!q[j-1]|w|u)|s&(!q[j+1]|w|u)|u&(!p[j]|t|s)|w&(!(b[i+1]||[])[j]|t|s)?c:'-@#'[v]),v=q[j],w=y>7-v,u=y<v).join``).join``,p=q,q=b[i]).join`
`,h=q=[],k=[...'01234567']).join`
`
```

*Less golfed*

```js
a=>b=>a.map((r,i)=>
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(y=>
    (h+=' ') + r.map((c,j)=>
      [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(x=> (
        t=x<v, s=x>7-v,
        v == 0 
        || t && (!B[i][j-1] | w|u)
        || s && (!B[i][j+1] | w|u)
        || u && (!(B[i-1]||[])[j] | t|s)
        || w && (!(B[i+1]||[])[j] | t|s)
        ? c : '-@#'[v] )
      , v = B[i][j], w=y>7-v,u=y<v).join``
    ).join``
  ).join`\n`
,h = '').join`\n`
```

**Test**

```js
F=
a=>b=>a.map((r,i)=>k.map(y=>(h+=' ')+r.map((c,j)=>k.map(x=>(t=x<v,s=x>7-v,!v|t&(!q[j-1]|w|u)|s&(!q[j+1]|w|u)|u&(!p[j]|t|s)|w&(!(b[i+1]||[])[j]|t|s)?c:'-@#'[v]),v=q[j],w=y>7-v,u=y<v).join``).join``,p=q,q=b[i]).join`
`,h=q=[],k=[...'01234567']).join`
`

A=[['a','b','a'],['b','a','b'],['a','b','a']]
B=[[1,1,1],[2,0,1],[2,0,0]]

O.textContent = F(A)(B)+'\n'
A=[['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.'],['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.'],['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '1']]
B=[[0,1,0,0,1,2,0],[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[0,2,0,0,0,1,0]]

O.textContent += F(A)(B)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 857 bytes

Not really what anyone could call "golfed" but since nobody else seems to have entered anything at all, I figured this was a start. It's massive, but it seems to work. Will make an effort to golf it tomorrow if I get the time.

```
function a($a,$b){$c=sizeof($a);$d=sizeof($a[0]);for($e=0;$e<$c;$e++){for($f=0;$f<$d;$f++){$A=$GLOBALS['h']=$a[$e][$f];$i=$GLOBALS['i']=$b[$e][$f];$B=j($i==1&&$b[$e-1][$f]>0);$C=j($i==1&&$b[$e][$f+1]>0);$D=j($i==1&&$b[$e+1][$f]>0);$E=j($i==1&&$b[$e][$f-1]>0);$F=j($i>0&&$b[$e-1][$f]>0);$G=j($i>0&&$b[$e][$f+1]>0);$H=j($i>0&&$b[$e+1][$f]>0);$I=j($i>0&&$b[$e][$f-1]>0);$J=j($i==1);$K=j($i==1||($i>1&&$b[$e-1][$f]>0));$L=j($i==1||($i>1&&$b[$e][$f+1]>0));$M=j($i==1||($i>1&&$b[$e+1][$f]>0));$N=j($i==1||($i>1&&$b[$e][$f-1]>0));$O=j($i>0);$P=$e*8;$g[$P].="$A$B$F$F$F$F$B$A";$g[$P+1].="$E$J$K$K$K$K$J$C";$l="$I$N$O$O$O$O$L$G";$g[$P+2].=$l;$g[$P+3].=$l;$g[$P+4].=$l;$g[$P+5].=$l;$g[$P+6].="$E$J$M$M$M$M$J$C";$g[$P+7].="$A$D$H$H$H$H$D$A";}}foreach($g as$h){echo str_repeat(' ', $i++)."$h\n";}}function j($k){return($k)?strtr($GLOBALS['i'],'12','@#'):$GLOBALS['h'];}
```

Test case

```
error_reporting(0);
$a=[[a,b,a],[b,a,b],[a,b,a]];
$b=[[1,1,1],[2,0,1],[2,0,0]];
a($a,$b);
```

Output

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
 a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
  a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
   a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
    a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
     a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
      a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@a
       a@@@@@@abbbbbbbba@@@@@@a
        bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
         bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
          bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
           bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
            bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
             bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
              bb####bbaaaaaaaab@@@@@@b
               bb####bbaaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
                aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                 aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                  aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                   aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                    aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                     aa####aabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                      aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
                       aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa
```

Test case

```
error_reporting(0);
$a=[['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.'],['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '.'],['.', ',', '.', ',', '.', ',', '1']];
$b=[[0,1,0,0,1,2,0],[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[0,2,0,0,0,1,0]];
a($a,$b);
```

Output

```
........,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,........
 ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@,,,,,,,,........
  ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@######,,........
   ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@######,,........
    ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@######,,........
     ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@######,,........
      ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@@,,####,,........
       ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,.@@@@@@.,,####,,........
        ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,..####..,,####,,........
         .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@,,,,,,,,..####..,,####,,........
          .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##############################..
           .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##############################..
            .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##############################..
             .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@##############################..
              .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@,,,,,,,,........,,####,,........
               ........,@@@@@@,........,,,,,,,,........,,####,,........
                ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                 ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                  ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                   ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                    ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                     ........,,####,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                      ........,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,........,@@@@@@,11111111
                       ........,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,........,,,,,,,,11111111
```

Test case

```
error_reporting(0);
$a=[[p,p,p,p,h,h,h,p,p,p,p],[p,p,p,p,h,h,h,p,p,p,p],[p,p,p,p,h,h,h,p,p,p,p],[p,p,p,p,h,h,h,p,p,p,p],[p,p,p,p,h,h,h,p,p,p,p]];
$b=[[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]];
a($a,$b);
```

Output

```
pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppphhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
 p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
  p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
   p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
    p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
     p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
      p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
       p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
        p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
         p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
          p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
           p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
            p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
             p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
              p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
               p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
                p@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@pppppppppp@@@@@@p
                 p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                  p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                   p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                    p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                     p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                      p@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ppppppppph@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@p
                       p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                        p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                         p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                          p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                           p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                            p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                             p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                              p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                               p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                 p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                  p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                   p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                    p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                     p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                      p@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppppppppppph@@@@@@hhhhhhhhhh@@@@@@hppppppppp@@@@@@ppppppppppppppppp
                                       pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppphhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhpppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java - 661 bytes

Hi! This is my first submission here. If I did something wrong please tell me.

```
static void m(char[][]b,int[][]t){String z="";int w=b[0].length;int h=b.length;char[][]r=new char[h*8][w*8];for(int j=0;j<h;j++){for(int i=0;i<w;i++){for(int x=0;x<8;x++)for(int y=0;y<8;y++){r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=b[j][i];int n=t[j][i];if(n!=0){char c;int d,e;if(n==1){c='@';e=0;d=7;}else{c='#';e=1;d=6;}if(x>e&&y>e&&x<d&&y<d)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;if(x>e&&x<d){if(j>0&&y<2&&t[j-1][i]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;if(j<h-1&&y>5&&t[j+1][i]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;}if(y>e&&y<d){if(i>0&&x<2&&t[j][i-1]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;if(i<w-1&&x>5&&t[j][i+1]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;}}}}for(int l=0;l<8;l++){System.out.println(z+Arrays.toString(r[j*8+l]).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]|[, ]\\s",""));z+=" ";}}}
```

[You can try it here :)](https://tio.run/##pVPBcpswEL3nK1Q6YyDIBDLT1h1ZmeYDesoR6yBAsUVl8IAcQyjf7q5k8NiduJcKW9p9etr3tMYFf@PzaifKIv/1/Si3u6rWqAAw3Gupwue65l1D7nb7VMkMZYo3DfrJZYn6OwRjxBvNNSxvlczRFna9F13Lco14vW4S5o9kM7INrxOWsBRR1Pcud7Gbwpe7A@7HyCAmu9gbyLmALLU5r@35GMMD3EccndfIsB8ebgiGLkZQE6aPIyP8/5zYvTZxZRqsGpswg12oZS8BsX0gj7C9hmVEl1ffeinW/ikfjlc9987XxJOW348/wjt1HAIoOtA0iVioRLnWG4tsaDqlU4GaluJw6trmfsGSA0zktao9wy9oRIrlhhRB4PcTKAGUywORl2ALYLtckBbACesA6wDrDLFOivtF0LFEwtIysFZAzKytkuope/XKTzTye2MIZXY3x8LilMaAU/eHSwRUzuk3MgjVCIN9NlgM2FcyALd9ErNZZ6Z2mUO0zP2/9TMy8YDi95AUT5GhPs5m4GYeGz/GyocHoSnz2Eh8sezgH2zjx1rpRh1pdNpRB4ggdVMH@mx02lEHNoNb7AHG1HkF/VHQeWU6/9I1WmzDaq/DHbwgWpXee3D6o4e6Or003qmeYn5Yi53imXhWynOS1Qo@jP1OMGKrVeNgx/F98h5QBzlG8Tgc/wA)

Unminified:

```
static void m(char[][] b, int[][] t) {
    String z="";
    int w=b[0].length;int h=b.length;
    char[][]r=new char[h*8][w*8];
    for(int j=0;j<h;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)for(int y=0;y<8;y++){
                r[j*8+y][i*8+x] = b[j][i];
                int n=t[j][i];
                if(n!=0){
                    char c;int d,e;
                    if(n==1){c='@';e=0;d=7;}
                    else{c='#';e=1;d=6;}
                    if(x>e&&y>e&&x<d&&y<d)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;

                    if(x>e&&x<d){
                        if(j>0&&y<2&&t[j-1][i]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;
                        if(j<h-1&&y>5&&t[j+1][i]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;
                    }
                    if(y>e&&y<d){
                        if(i>0&&x<2&&t[j][i-1]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;
                        if(i<w-1&&x>5&&t[j][i+1]!=0)r[j*8+y][i*8+x]=c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int l=0;l<8;l++){System.out.println(z+Arrays.toString(r[j*8+l]).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]|[, ]\\s",""));z+=" ";}
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I must have forgotten to update the static version. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @100Toby1 Hi Toby, Welcome and nice answer, you can change your `and`s to bitwise `and`s `&&`->`&` for a few bytes.

Comment: also if you init `c='#',d=6,e=1` then you can remove the else ` else{c='#';e=1;d=6;}`

Comment: [616 bytes](https://ideone.com/TnFxG1)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 299 bytes

```
(a,b,g=(x,y)=>!(b[y]||0)[x],u=s=r='',L='length',R='repeat')=>{for(y=v=-1;++y<a[L];)for(i=v;++i<8;)for(x=v,s+=`
`+r,r+=' ';m=b[y][++x],W=Q=a[y][x],W+=(Z=~m&1)?Q:u,D=(A=i<m)|(B=i>7-m)?W:u,p=g(x-1,y)?W:D,q=g(x+1,y)?W:D,x<a[0][L];)s+=p+(A&&g(x,y-1)||B&&g(x,y+1)||!m?Q:'@#'[Z])[R](8-(p+q)[L])+q;return s}
```

## [Try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/49o68k90/)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>275 268 266 264</s> 252 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET[a]as$y=>$r)for($z=8;$z--;)for($x=-print"
".$f.=" ";$w--||$c=$r[++$x+!$w=7];)echo[$a=($s=($m=$_GET[b])[$y])[$x+1],$a|$b=2>$n=$s[$x],1,1,1,1,$b|$a=$s[$x-1],$a][$w]*[$a=$m[$y+1][$x],$a|$b,1,1,1,1,$b|$a=$m[$y-1][$x],$a][$z]*$n?" @#"[$n]:$c;
```

takes input from GET parameters `a` and `b`, prints to STDOUT.
[Try it online.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6f0bacf1895e4a5202b16ff392dac3accb86d77)

**breakdown**

```php
foreach($_GET[a]as$y=>$r)   # loop 1: through rows of first array
    for($z=8;$z--;)             # loop 2: $z from 7 to 0 (line = 8*$y+7-$z)
        for($x=-print"\n".$f.=" ";  # print newline and padding
            $w--                        # loop 4: loop $w from 7 to 0 (column = 8*$x+7-$w)
            ||$c=$r[++$x+!$w=7];)   # loop 3: loop $c through characters in row
                echo
                [                               # vertical test
                    $a=($s=($m=$_GET[b])[$y])[$x+1],    # $m=2nd array, $s=current row
                                                        # $a=block to the right has road
                    $a|$b=2>$n=$s[$x],                  # $b=current block has brick road
                    1,1,1,1,
                    $b|$a=$s[$x-1],                     # $a=block to the left has road
                    $a
                ][$w]                               # index tests
                *
                [                               # horizontal test
                    $a=$m[$y+1][$x],                    # $a=block below has road
                    $a|$b,
                    1,1,1,1,
                    $b|$a=$m[$y-1][$x],                 # $a=block above has road
                    $a
                ][$z]                               # index tests
                *$n                             # is a road in this block?
                ?" @#"[$n]:$c;                  # if block&v-test&h-test then print road
                                                # else print character from 1st array
```